# How to quickly get private keys from mnemonic phrases

Tags: private-key, java, mnemonic

I need to get private keys (ethereum/bitcoin and other currencies) from mnemonic phrases as fast as possible. At the moment I am using BitcoinJ library:

```
Set<BigInteger> privateKeys = new HashSet<>();
for (String mnemonic : mnemonics) {
    try {
        DeterministicSeed deterministicSeed = new DeterministicSeed(mnemonic, null, "", 0);
        DeterministicKeyChain deterministicKeyChain = DeterministicKeyChain.builder().seed(deterministicSeed).build();
        DeterministicKey deterministicKey = deterministicKeyChain.getKeyByPath(ETHEREUM_HD_PATH, true);
        privateKeys.add(deterministicKey.getPrivKey());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Obtaining a private key this way takes on average ~10 ms. Are there any ways to speed up this process (without using a video card)?

Comment: Generating the private key involves using a hashing function, that should take most of the time. You could try using a low-level language like C, rust or assembly.